# Please Correct the SQL query

Tags: sql-server

My table data:

[image]

My query:

```
select a._id, a.name,b.pic_name 
from Table_1 a 
inner join Table_2 b on a.a_id = b.a_id  
group by a.name, b.pic_name 
order by b.Date desc
```

Result:

```
1   jawad  a
1   jawad  b
2   ahmed  c
2   ahmed  d
```

Expected result:

```
1 jawad a
2 ahmed c
3 abbasi 
4 JD
```

I want to display any 1 pic_name from the table_2 that is join with table_1

Comment: Your question is missing logic needed for choosing a picture from the second table.

Comment: once your edition completed please inform then other can ans for this que.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Below Code Once

```
create table #tab (a_id bigint ,name varchar(50))

create table #tab1 (id bigint,a_Id bigint,pic_Name varchar(50),date_ INT)

insert into #tab values(1,'Jawad'),(2,'Ahmed'),(3,'Abbasi'),(4,'JD')

INSERT INTO #tab1 VALUES(1,1,'A',1),(2,1,'B',2),(3,2,'C',3),(4,2,'D',4)

;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT   A.a_id,A.name,pic_Name,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY A.A_ID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RNUM FROM #tab A
LEFT JOIN #tab1 B ON A.a_id=B.a_Id
) 
SELECT a_id,name,pic_Name FROM CTE C
WHERE RNUM IN(SELECT MIN(RNUM) FROM CTE  GROUP BY A_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's not entirely clear in the question, it looks like what you want is the picture name associated with either the earliest or latest date, for pictures associated with a certain person. If you're using SQL Sevver 2012+, a window function will do exactly what you're after:

```
select distinct
  a.a_id,
  a.name,
  last_value(b.pic_name) over (partition by b.a_id
                               order by b.date desc
                               range between current row and unbounded following) as pic_name
from Table_1 a
left outer join Table_2 b
on a.a_id = b.a_id
```

It's not clear from the code and example data given whether you want the picture associated with the latest date or the earliest date - but a quick change of `desc` to `asc` in the `order by` will reverse this. As it stands, I've written it to match your expected output.

Here's the temp tables I created so you can try this out. Please note I've amended the dates to actually be dates, as ordering by the date doesn't make too much sense otherwise. If this is wrong, please clarify why the dates are single-digit integers, and I'll amend this.

(In order to get the query working on the temp tables, simply add `#` in front of the table names.)

```
create table #Table_1 (
  a_id int,
  name varchar(20)
);

create table #Table_2 (
  id int,
  a_id int,
  pic_name varchar(20),
  date date
);

insert into #Table_1
values (1, 'jawad');
insert into #Table_1
values (2, 'ahmed');
insert into #Table_1
values (3, 'Abbasi');
insert into #Table_1
values (4, 'JD');

insert into #Table_2
values (1, 1, 'a', '2016-01-01');
insert into #Table_2
values (2, 1, 'b', '2016-01-02');
insert into #Table_2
values (3, 2, 'c', '2016-01-03');
insert into #Table_2
values (4, 2, 'd', '2016-01-04');
```

If you don't yet understand window functions, they are really worth getting to grips with. I strongly suggest this two part series ([Part 1](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/window-functions-in-sql-server/), [Part 2](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/window-functions-in-sql-server-part-2-the-frame/)) which starts by explaining windows functions in general, and then moves onto explaining the frame (which will help you understand the `range between` part of the above query).

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
SELECT  A.A_ID, A.NAME,
        ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 B.PIC_NAME
                FROM TABLE_2 B
                WHERE B.A_ID = A.A_ID
                ORDER BY B.PIC_NAME), '') AS PIC_NAME
FROM TABLE_1 A
```

Answer (score -1):

Add ID to the grouping and select the min Name:

```
select  a._id, a.name, MIN(b.pic_name)
from Table_1 a 
inner join Table_2 b on a.a_id=p.a_id 
GROUP BY a._id, a.name,
Order by b.Date desc
```

Comment: INNERJOIN will not give expected output. Take a look at sample data.

Answer (score -1):

Use Distinct key word like below

```
 select a._id, a.name,b.pic_name 
from Table_1 a 
inner join Table_2 b on a.a_id = b.a_id  
group by a.name 
order by b.Date desc
```

Comment: this is the typing mistke i know that plz correct the concept of the query to display the expected result

Comment: then use distinct key word during selection  like SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: if you use distinct then you don't need to use GROUP BY

Comment: @JawadAhmed check the the answer i made changes to it hope it works for you

Comment: DISTINCT will not give expected output. Take a look at sample data.

Answer (score -1):

try this...

```
SELECT a._id, a.name,b.pic_name 
    FROM Table_1 a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_2 b ON a.a_id = b.a_id AND b.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Table_2 WHERE a_id = a.a_id);
```

Comment: Going to Table_2 is not the best solution since you can go there once.